# Right click a location and move towards it (C# Monogame)

Tags: c#, movement, monogame

I would like the player to move towards the mouse when the player right clicks. The player does move, but doesn't stop when the player reaches the point. 
Here is the code.

```
void playerUpdate(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float dT = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        player.pos.X += player.vel.X * dT;
        player.pos.Y += player.vel.Y * dT;

        player.checkDest(x2y2, player.pos);


        if ((mouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && (player.moving == false))
        {
            x2y2.X = mouse.X;
            x2y2.Y = mouse.Y;

            player.move(x2y2, player.pos);

        }
    }
```

The player's file,

```
        public void move(Vector2 dest, Vector2 pos)
    {
        dist.X = pos.X - dest.X;
        dist.Y = pos.Y - dest.Y;

        vel.X -= dist.X;
        vel.Y -= dist.Y;

        moving = true;
    }

    public void checkDest(Vector2 dest, Vector2 pos)
    {
        if (pos == dest)
        {
            vel.X = 0;
            vel.Y = 0;
            moving = false;
        }
    }
```

I assume it is because of the player's position and its use of decimals and the mouse position being integers. How could I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare player's distance to the destination and if it's small enough, stop. So replace this line:

```
if (pos == dest)
```

with

```
if (Vector2.Distance( pos, dest ) < 0.1f) // Adjust the value if it's not good
```

Comment: Aditionally to 'stop' when close enough is to 'set' the object to the exact target position. Trivia: the 0.1 value is often referred to as *epsilon*, the greek symbol used to indicate the margin of error due to floatingpoint arithmic. So often you'll encounter code like "if (a<= epsilon)" where epsilon is defined as a constant.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware that there was a distance method. That really helps.